# How to Wrap Observable Around Office.js Excel Event Handler

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, promise, office-js

Within Office.js, specifically Excel, you can add/register Event Handlers (which are technically Promises). So for instance, Microsoft's documentation gives this example:

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheet.onAdded.add(onWorksheetAdd);

    await context.sync();
    console.log("A handler has been registered for the OnAdded event.");
});
```

I am currently working in Angular though so I want to "wrangle" all this `async` code into `observable` to have some sense of control over everything happening on the Excel document. In the above example, we are listening to when User adds a new Worksheet. `onWorksheetAdd` will register that Event Handler so that when the User executes the action (adding a new worksheet), the `onWorksheetAdd` callback/promise will be called.

Below is what I currently have.

`excel-worksheet.service.ts`

```
registerOnAddWorksheetHandler() {
        return from(
            // @ts-ignore
            Excel.run((context) => {
                    let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets;
                    sheet.onAdded.add(this.excelEventHandlerService.onAddWorksheetHandler) ; // must pass Promise as argument

                    console.log("A handler has been registered for the OnAdded event.");
                }
                return context.sync();
            })
        );
    }
```

`excel-event-handler.service.ts`

```
 onAddWorksheetHandler(event): Promise<any> {
        return of(
            // @ts-ignore
            Excel.run((context) => {
                    console.log("Handler for worksheet onAdded event has been triggered. Newly added worksheet Id : " + event.worksheetId, event);

                return context.sync();
            })
        )
        .toPromise()
    }
```

**Essentially, what I want is to wrap the event handler in an Observable so that my `app.component.ts` can register the information to my application.**

I have tried the following:

- Within `onAddWorksheetHandler`, I have attempted to continue to resolve the Promises. By that I called `.then()` after `context.sync()`, followed by calling it again on `Excel.run()`, followed by calling it after `toPromise()`. This is unsuccessfully though because `registerOnAddWorksheetHandler` has registered the event and won't have access to it's value. Mainly because Office.js is Promise based so execution is one and done.
- I have tried declaring a `Subject` on `excel-event-handler.service.ts` so that `app.component.ts` can have access but that also failed. I'm not sure if the event handler registered is swallowing anything trying to be bubbled up.

My last effort to try to resolve this is just to move those registered event handlers to `app.component.ts` to have access to the scope. I was hoping to have done this a bit more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

This was an misunderstanding on my end.A case of not seeing the forest for the trees. For office.js event handlers, you only need to execute the `Excel.run()` and the `context.sync()` command in order to actually just register `<some_callback()>`.

```
Excel.run((context) => {
  let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets;
  sheet.onAdded.add(<some_callback()>);
  return context.sync();
})
```

Where my confusion laid was I assumed that whole `Excel.run()` dance had to all be executed within the `<some_callback()>`. Turns out it does not, you can have that just be your typical JS callback. Within Angular, that can be any method from the component that needs to be executed. Same logic would apply with any other framework.

I hope this helps others.